# Admin Site appending letter "s" to end of each model\table name on Django

Tags: django, django-models

I tried the verbose name when registering it on my admin.py so that it would appear as Data instead of Datas but that did not work.

> admin.site.register(Data, verbose_name="Data")

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22):

You should be setting `verbose_name_plural` in that case. Docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural).

Also you should be setting it on the model's `Meta` options of your model (docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#model-meta-options)). Example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # my fields

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "PluralForMyModel"
```