# Django admin panel renders "s" after table/model names

Tags: django, sqlite

I have no idea what's going on, here's a screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659308/admin-site-appending-letter-s-to-end-of-each-model-table-name-on-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dirkgroten said, It happens because Django always uses `verbose_name_plural` in the admin site's section headings, which is `verbose_name` + "s"

You can add another class called `Meta` in your model to specify custom plural display name. For example

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):

     ....
    # fields
       ....

    class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "SomeNewName"
```

This `SomeNewName` will be the model name irrespective of data inside the table.

Comment: Whether there's data in the table has nothing to do with plural. Even with 0 items in the database, it will be plural. Django always uses `verbose_name_plural` in the admin site's section headings, which is `verbose_name` + "s" by default (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#verbose-name))